# Fetching the data from the API and add it dynamically to the table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am adding rows dynamically to my table:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from "axios";

class ShipmentsTable extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            shipments: [
                {
                    requestType: "Request Type",
                    customerName: "",
                    email: "",
                    companyName: "",
                   
                },
            ]
        };

        this.listRequest = this.listRequest.bind();
    }

    getShipments = () =>{
        axios.get("http://localhost:8000/app/shipments/list/")
            .then((response) =>{
                let result = response.data;
                console.log(result.data);
            }).catch((error) =>{
            console.log(error);
        });
    }


    listRequest = () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState(() => ({
                shipments: [
                     /* These objects need to be replaced with api fetched data */
                    {
                        requestType: "Request Type",
                        customerName: "kjldfsj",
                        email: "dlfkjsdlf",
                        companyName: "dfdsafdsa",
                        
                    },
                    {
                        requestType: "Request Type",
                        customerName: "kjldfsj",
                        email: "dlfkjsdlf",
                        companyName: "dfdsafdsa",
                        
                    }
                ]
            }));
        }, 1000);
    };


    componentDidMount() {
        this.listRequest();
        this.getShipments();
    }


    addRow = ({ requestType, customerName, email, companyName}) => {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{requestType}</td>
                <td>{customerName}</td>
                <td>{email}</td>
                <td>{companyName}</td>
            </tr>
        );
    };


    render(){
        return(
            <table className="submittedShipmentsTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr id="myTableHeader">
                        <td>
                            <th>Request Type</th>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <th>Customer Name</th>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <th>Email</th>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <th>Company Name</th>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                {/*Adding Rows Automatically*/}
                {this.state.shipments.map((shipment, index) => this.addRow(shipment))}


                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }
}

export default ShipmentsTable;
```

I am having objects displayed in my table as follows, it displays those objects in the table, however I want to display the data fetched from the api instead:

```
listRequest = () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState(() => ({
                shipments: [
                    /* These objects need to be replaced with api fetched data */
                    {
                        requestType: "Request Type",
                        customerName: "kjldfsj",
                        email: "dlfkjsdlf",
                        companyName: "dfdsafdsa",
                        
                    },
                    {
                        requestType: "Request Type",
                        customerName: "kjldfsj",
                        email: "dlfkjsdlf",
                        companyName: "dfdsafdsa",
                        
                    }
                ]
            }));
        }, 1000);
    };
```

**My Question:**
*What I want to do is to add the data fetched from the api dynamically to the table in the shipments object that is in the listRequest() method.*

Comment: better use async await , store the result in state using setState() and then use the state to show the fetched data .... can you attach a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new) of what you tried ?

Comment: can you please highlight the problem you are facing

Answer (score 0):

Just set to state the data received from API

```
getShipments = () =>{
    axios.get("http://localhost:8000/app/shipments/list/")
        .then((response) => {
           this.setState({ shipments: response.data });
        }).catch((error) =>{
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Forgot to parse response, updated the answer

Comment: Why do you need `listRequest` method at all?
The only thing you need - is to fetch data on mount, i guess

Comment: Sorry, i missed that fact that you are using axios.
What is the output of response.data then? Why do you getting `undefined`